# How to do in Resttemplate Spring

Tags: java, resttemplate

```
curl -u "uname:password" -H "X-Requested-With: Curl" -X "POST" "https://qualysapi.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/qps/rest/3.0/search/was/wasscan/" > was_finding.txt
```

How to do the same thing in Spring rest template,

```
curl -u "uname:password" -H "X-Requested-With: Curl" -X "POST" "https://qualysapi.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/qps/rest/3.0/search/was/wasscan/" > was_finding.txt
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure why you have the same request two times. Anyhow, you need to initiate a rest client, that you can reuse, and then use it is as a simple http client for any calls:

```
// Do once
HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(factory));

// Do anytime
byte[] plainCredsBytes = "uname:password".getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
        "https://qualysapi.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/qps/rest/3.0/search/was/wasscan/",
        new HttpEntity(headers), String.class);

if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
    Files.writeString(Paths.get("was_finding.txt"), response.getBody());
} else {
    // Handle status code, etc.
}
```

If you need to set up SSL then you need to create a SSLContextBuilder before you build your client, thats it.